# angular reactive form valuechanges with pipe. IS THIS A BUG ???

Tags: angular, rxjs, reactive-programming, angular-reactive-forms, reactive

Seems like pipe doesn't work with reactive form control valueChanges. i've prepared this https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vdeqrz  so that you can reproduce the problem.

type something in the text field. then type "boom" (without the quotes). after the error catch, the control does not work any more. 
you can verify typing something new on it after that. it does not detect any other input.

if you refresh the page, then it works again.

am i missing something here ?

Comment: Why you want to throw error. You can return of(false/null) right?

Comment: Actually this is a stupid question, it should be deleted from SO. I was sleepless when i created it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a bug. Every Rx stream can emit zero or more `next` notifications and one `error` or `complete` notification but never both.

So if you use `throwError` the chain will dispose itself because you can never have the same chain emitting two or more `error` notification which is what you expect.

There're obviously many ways to avoid this. You can use something different than `throwError` and wrap the input value with some object for example. But then you won't be able to handle it in observer's `error` handler.

You can also use `retry` and `tap` to handle the error:

```
this.query.valueChanges
  .pipe(
    switchMap(d => (d === 'boom') ? throwError(new Error("boom")) :  of(d)),
    tap({ error: err => console.log(err) }),
    retry(),
  )
  .subscribe({
    next: d => console.log(d),
    complete: () => console.log("complete")
  })
```

You'd have to use `tap` here because the error never reaches the observers.

Your updated demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1qfn2z?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Answer (score 0):

rxjs throw error operator will stop the observable from emitting again just like you have unsubscribe from the valueChanges observable
try like this intand of using throwError operator just throw new `Error` object

```
this.query.valueChanges
  .pipe(map(d => (d === 'boom') ? new Error("boom") :  d))
  .subscribe(
    d => console.log(d),
    err => console.log(err),
    () => console.log("complete")
  )
```

Answer (score -1):

Yeah you're definitely missing something.

Open your console (the browser one, not the blitz one) and see that you actually have an error :

```
Error: boom
    at SwitchMapSubscriber.eval [as project] (app.component.ts:43)
    at SwitchMapSubscriber._next (switchMap.ts:100)
    at SwitchMapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.ts:102)
    at SafeSubscriber.schedulerFn [as _next] (event_emitter.ts:88)
    at SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (Subscriber.ts:270)
    at SafeSubscriber.next (Subscriber.ts:212)
    at Subscriber._next (Subscriber.ts:142)
    at Subscriber.next (Subscriber.ts:102)
    at EventEmitter.Subject.next (Subject.ts:62)
    at EventEmitter.emit (event_emitter.ts:78)
```

This is what is messing with your application.