# Rxjs retry() keep calling

Tags: angular, error-handling, rxjs

Rx stream emits only one error, but as per our requirement I wanted to have that stream alive even after an error. For that, I have used many solutions and in this particular solution, retry() keep calling resulting keep getting same error. For most people, this solution is working. What am I missing here?

```
merge(this.paginator.page, this.field.valueChanges)
  .pipe(
    startWith({}),
    debounceTime(500),
    distinctUntilChanged(),
    switchMap(() => {
      this.isLoadingResults = true;
      this.List = [];
      return this.getList();
    }),
    tap({error: err => console.log(err)}),
    retry(),
  ).subscribe(data => console.log(data));
```

I have used solution from this link,
[angular reactive form valuechanges with pipe. IS THIS A BUG ???](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51650890/angular-reactive-form-valuechanges-with-pipe-is-this-a-bug), doesn't work on my case though.

**Edit** - I think people have difficulties understanding what end result I want. Sorry for that. So basically after merge throw error, it stopped working. What I want is that, even after error if I change value(trigger valueChange), it should give me the result(API should called).

Comment: is it retrying or not?

Comment: So it works or doesn't work or what? How do you know it keeps repeating? What do you even want it to do?

Comment: @ashishpal it is keep retrying and keep throwing error.

Comment: @martin How do I know it keeps repeating? by looking at console, where I can see it keep calling API after an error and throws same error.
What do I want to do - As I said, in simple words even after an error, Rx stream should stay alive.

Comment: You have used `merge` it means everytime the observable emits a value, you will have your whole pipe and subscription being ran. That's why you're seeing it everytime. If you want to close a stream on error, use `unsubscribe` on your subscription to stop listening to events.

Comment: try using `catchError` so it would not throw and stops the Rx

Comment: If you see repeated calls then `retry` is working. What else you expect to happen on every retry the chain fails? `retry()` will just resubscribe and it will error again.